# Remove white background in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, crop, transparent, uigraphicscontext

I am using `UIBezierPath` to draw the lines in white background and black stroke using fingers and the touch end method I am cropping the image using `CGGraphicsContext()` and which is working fine. I would like to remove the white background and make it as transparent. I have tried several codes and which is not working to me. The below code makes the entire image transparent. Any one can help me to make the image as transparent except the black stroke. Thanks in advance. Sorry if the question is already asked.

```
-(UIImage*) makeTransparent : (UIImage*) viewImage
{
    CGImageRef rawImageRef = viewImage.CGImage;
    const float colorMasking[6] = {255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255};
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewImage.size);
    CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, viewImage.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, viewImage.size.width, viewImage.size.height), maskedImageRef);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use `UIImageView` for display `UIImage` then just set BackgroundColor to `clearColor` like bellow...

```
        [yourImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. When I am cropping the I have used UIJpegRepresentation instead of UIPNGRepresentation. It fixed my issue.